# How to count the number of sub-sequences in a string?

Tags: python, string, substring

This program is to count the number of sub-strings in a string.

Test case:
    string `ABCDCDC`
    pattern `CDC`

The answer should be `2` but I am getting `0`.

```
def count_substring(string, sub_string):
  for i in range(0,len(string)-len(sub_string)+1):
    count=0
    for j in range(0,len(sub_string)):
       if(string[i+j]!=sub_string[j]):
           break;
    if j==len(sub_string):
       count=count+1
    return count
```

Comment: Make sure your indentation is correct when you post...

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the `for j in range(0,len(sub_string))` loop `j` can be at most `len(sub_string)-1` (if you don't break early). So `if j==len(sub_string):` is always `False`. You want `if j==len(sub_string)-1:` or simply `else:` (meaning you've reached the end of the `for` loop) instead.

Also `count = 0` should be initialized at the start, not in the first `for` loop:

```
def count_substring(string, sub_string):
    count=0
    for i in range(0,len(string)-len(sub_string)+1):
        for j in range(0,len(sub_string)):
            if(string[i+j]!=sub_string[j]):
                break;
        else:
            count=count+1
    return count
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings are sequences of 1-character substrings in Python, so you can use the built-in [`count()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range) method — in other words, you don't have to re-invent the wheel and write your own function to do it.

```
test_string = 'ABCDCDC'
sub_string = 'CDC'

print(test_string.count(sub_string))  # -> 2
```